# center text in a LI that the text is unknown length

Tags: css

I am building a bunch of list items in an un-ordered list. The list has a fixed size of `250px X 75px;`These list items are generated dynamically so i do not know what text will be displayed, so my li looks like this.

```
#pages-content li{
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I found one suggestion that said to make the line height `75px` and that worked until there is more than one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use lists? Can you use divs instead?

```
<style>
.div { 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 75px; 
  position: relative;
}

.container { 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 75px; 
  display: table; 
}

.container p {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center; 
}
</style>
<div class="div">
      <div class="container">
          <p>This text should look centered even if it's long.</p>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="div">
      <div class="container">
          <p>This text should look centered even if it's long.</p>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="div">
      <div class="container">
          <p>This text should look centered even if it's long.</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#pages-content ul li{
  width: 250px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pages-content">
    <ul>
        <li>Matter here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zLcT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For a purely HTML/CSS solution, try using a table and `vertical-align: middle` in the table cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zLcT/

If you can only use css, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

adding `display: table-cell` might work, as vertical-align is meant, more or less, for table data